# MapKit for SwiftUI Can't Wrap MapPolyline in Bool Controls

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

In a MapKit for SwiftUI iOS 17 app with MKRoutes to make polylines, I would like to place a ProgressView on top of the map while the routes are being drawn (and disable any other user interaction until complete). It seems that the MapPolyline() function needs to be in the Map closure and cannot be refactored outside but anything I have tried to wrap it in a task or in an if statement fails.

This is a simplified version to demonstrate:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var routes = [MKRoute]()
    @State private var showProgress: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map() {
            
                //want to start a ProgressView here
                if routes.count >= 1 {
                    ForEach(routes, id: \.self) { r in
                        MapPolyline(r)
                            .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                    }
                }// if routes
                //want to end a ProgressView here
            
            }
            .onAppear {
                makeSomeRoutes()
            }
            if showProgress {
                ProgressView()
                    .tint(.red)
                    .scaleEffect(4)
            }
        }//z
    }//body

    func makeSomeRoutes() {
    
        let lats: [CLLocationDegrees] = [
            37.338207,
            38.5816,
            39.1677,
            40.760780
        ]
    
        let longs: [CLLocationDegrees] = [
            -121.886330,
             -121.4944,
             -120.1452,
             -111.891045
        ]

        for r in 0..<3 {
            let request = MKDirections.Request()
            request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lats[r], longitude: longs[r])))
            request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lats[r + 1], longitude: longs[r + 1])))
        
            Task {
                let result = try? await MKDirections(request: request).calculate()
                let aRoute = result?.routes.first
            
                if let aRoute {
                    self.routes.append(aRoute)
                }
            }
        }//for
    }//make some routes

}//struct
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 15, iOS 17

Answer (score 1):

you could try this approach using an `Annotation` to hold the `ProgressView`.

```
// for testing, adjust accordingly
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.1677, longitude: -120.1452)

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Map() {
            if routes.count >= 1 {
                ForEach(routes, id: \.self) { r in
                    MapPolyline(r).stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                }
            } else {
                Annotation("", coordinate: center) {
                    ProgressView().tint(.red).scaleEffect(4)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        makeSomeRoutes()
    }
}//body
```

Comment: Very interesting..I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sadly, that does not work in my real app - the time to draw is longer. I'll try some variations.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `showProgress` state that controls the progress view, so all you need to do now is to make `makeSomeRoutes` into an `async` method, so that you can set `showProgress` to true before calling it, and to false after the routes have been fetched.

```
func makeSomeRoutes() async -> [MKRoute] {

    let lats: [CLLocationDegrees] = [
        37.338207,
        38.5816,
        39.1677,
        40.760780
    ]

    let longs: [CLLocationDegrees] = [
        -121.886330,
         -121.4944,
         -120.1452,
         -111.891045
    ]
    
    return await withTaskGroup(of: MKRoute?.self) { group in
        for r in 0..<3 {
            group.addTask {
                let request = MKDirections.Request()
                request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lats[r], longitude: longs[r])))
                request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lats[r + 1], longitude: longs[r + 1])))
                let result = try? await MKDirections(request: request).calculate()
                return result?.routes.first
            }
        }
        var routes = [MKRoute]()
        for await case let result? in group {
            routes.append(result)
        }
        return routes
    }
}//make some routes
```

```
// as far as I know, MKRoute *should* be thread safe - it's just some immutable data
extension MKRoute: @unchecked Sendable {}
```

Then you can set `showProgress` in a `task`:

```
Map {
    ...
}
.task {
    showProgress = true
    routes = await makeSomeRoutes()
    showProgress = false
}
```

You can also add a `.allowsHitTesting(!showProgress)` to disable interactions on the map when `showProgress` is true.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can adapt to my real app.

Comment: It's really the drawing of the polylines that is the issue, not the makeSomeRoutes. In all cases in my real app, the creation of the MKRoutes from the Directions calls is fast. The drawing of the polylines is fairly slow - I'm still unclear why that is the case. At any rate, it does not seem possible to wrap the MapPolyline with any controlling parameters.

Comment: @JohnSF Oh you mean the map rendering is slow? I misunderstood. I'm pretty sure you can't control that. Hopefully you can in the future though.